# Giving a input from text file to an sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using below sql query to update a single record from a table, which is taking input from user.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SPOOL D:\FC_USER_UNLOCK.TXT
ACCEPT USER PROMPT 'ENTER USER_ID: '
DECLARE 
ANY_USER_FOUND NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO ANY_USER_FOUND 
  FROM SM_USER_PROFILE S
  WHERE S.COD_USER_ID='&USER' AND ROWNUM <= 1;
  IF (ANY_USER_FOUND > 0) THEN
      UPDATE SM_USER_PROFILE S 
      SET S.FLG_LOGIN_STATE='N'
          , S.CTR_NO_FAILED_DAY=0
          , S.CTR_NO_FAILED_SEQ=0
          , S.FLG_STATUS='E'
      WHERE S.COD_USER_ID='&USER';
      COMMIT;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER UNLOCKED SUCCESSFULLY...!!!');
  ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTERED USER DOES NOT EXIST..PLZ TRY AGAIN...!!!');
  END IF;
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
```

The above is working fine, But now i need to update table by taking an input i.e. user_id from a text file an it can be one or multiple user_id's.

So Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: How is the structure of this text file? Maybe you can use an "external table" for that.

Comment: Have a look at the UTL_FILE package, which allows PL/SQL code to open read, and write external files. Best of luck.

Comment: Structure of text file will be in singular column of user id's.

Answer (score 0):

> " now i need to update table by taking an input i.e. user_id from a
>   text file "

PL/SQL is a server-side language, and it doesn't do interaction with users very well.  So your choices are:

1. Read a file on the database server.  There are a couple of choices here: UTL_FILE or an external table. UTL_FILE is probably the better option here.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS069).
2. Write a shell script (`.bat` file) to read a list of user IDs and submit them one at a time to a version of the script you have already.

In either case you will need a better way of dealing with the user-interaction.  You don't need to pre-check for the existence of User ID.  The update won't fail if the userID doesn't exist, so you could save yourself a whole read per execution.

```
BEGIN

  UPDATE SM_USER_PROFILE S 
  SET S.FLG_LOGIN_STATE='N'
      , S.CTR_NO_FAILED_DAY=0
      , S.CTR_NO_FAILED_SEQ=0
      , S.FLG_STATUS='E'
  WHERE S.COD_USER_ID='&USER';
  if sql%rowcount > 0 then
      COMMIT;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER UNLOCKED SUCCESSFULLY...!!!');
  else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTERED USER DOES NOT EXIST..PLZ TRY AGAIN...!!!');
  end if;
END;
/
```